# RewriteRule preserving path across environments

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

I'm trying to come up with some redirect rules that'll work on my local working directory and production. The problem being my local dev env works via "localhost/exp" where as the production works from the root of the domain "www.lorem.com".

Doing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ^rec.php /core/rec [R=301,L]
```

Works on production no worries, but on my local it redirects to : "localhost/core/rec", where as I want it to to be "localhost/exp/core/rec"

I'd prefer not to have to hardcode "exp" in there, so far I found the only way todo it is have seperate rules per environment, I could make it work on my local using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/exp/(.*)
RewriteRule ^rec.php /exp/core/rec [R=301,L]
```

Appreciate any help on this one. Thanks!

Comment: You may be able to try and experiment with the "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost" parameter in the .htaccess file. I haven't done this before though as I use Nginx, so just a suggestion on where to maybe look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix your RewriteRule(s) with a RewriteCond matching any of the 'server internals'.  *See the full list of server internals [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).*

**SERVER_NAME** is the one that jumps out at me as possibly the best to use, so for example your it would use this (additional) prefix to your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} localhost
```

or for other than localhost:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} !localhost
```

Comment: I tested this and it works.